# Parse string and order by parsed value

Tags: c#, linq, string, linq-to-nhibernate

i am trying to build linq expression to solve my problem. I have list of strings

```
List<string> arr = new List<string>();
arr.Add("<desc><ru>1</ru><en>3</en></desc>");
arr.Add("<desc><ru>2</ru><en>4</en></desc>");
```

i want to parse every item and order results

```
fake sample:
arr.Select(ParseItem("en")).OrderBy(x)
```

then we have two items in ru in order 1,2

Thanks for all and sorry for my bad English
Thanks for all response but how to convert now results to IQueryable

```
class Test { public string data { get; set; } } 
List<Test> arr = new List<Test>();

arr.Add(new Test { data = "<desc><ru>AAA</ru><en>One</en></desc>" });
arr.Add(new Test { data = "<desc><ru>1</ru><en>Two</en></desc>" });
arr.Add(new Test { data = "<desc><ru>22</ru><en>Ab</en></desc>" });
IQueryable<Test> t = arr.AsQueryable();

// here the trouble how to convert to IQueryable<Test>
t = t.Select(s => XElement.Parse(s.data)).Select(x => x.Element("en")).
OrderBy(el => el.Value);
```

Thanks again

Comment: It's not clear why the code you have given would do anything with `ru`... or what you're doing with the expression you've given (which isn't valid anyway, in terms of the arguments).

Comment: Can you not use XML instead of just bare strings? It will open up a lot of possibilities in line with `XDocument`

Comment: @Jon Skeet Thanks for response, ru ot en its my input parameter witch i want to pa to some function and then it get a part of string between <ru> and </ru> and in last i want to sort all results...

Comment: @Bazzz Thanks for response no i cant i cant change that string (( i cant use xml

Comment: @Sanja: But you've called `ParseItem("en")`, not `ParseItem("ru")`...

Comment: @Sanja - Are you trying to order the elements by parsing the contents of an element as a numeric value and sorting by that?

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks yes, but there can be text, not only integers

Comment: @Sanja - If there are a mix of numbers and text how do you expect them to be sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the question update - this will return your ordered data by `<en>` node value:

```
var result = arr
    .OrderBy(t=>
        XElement.Parse(t.data).Element("en").Value
    );
```

The result valiable is of `IOrderedEnumerable<Test>` type.

Comment: Hi thanks, how to return not temporary items but original IQueryable<string> t = arr.AsQueryable();
t = t.Select(s => XElement.Parse(s)).Select(x => x.Element("en")).OrderBy(el => el.Value);

Answer (score 2):

This will produce a list of the values in `ru` tags (assuming they are integers), ordered by the values in `en` tags (again, assuming integers).

```
List<string> items = arr.Select(s => XElement.Parse(s))
                        .OrderBy(xml => (int)xml.Element("en"))
                        .Select(xml => (int)xml.Element("ru"))
                        .ToList();
```

If you simply want to enumerate, you can omit the `ToList` call:

```
foreach (var item in arr.Select(s => XElement.Parse(s))
                        .OrderBy(xml => (int)xml.Element("en"))
                        .Select(xml => (int)xml.Element("ru")))
{
    // do something with item
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I've got what the excepted results are, but if you need to select values in `en` ordered by the value in `ru` then here it is:

```
var orderedItems = (
    from item in arr
    let x = XElement.Parse(item)
    let ruValue = (int)x.Element("ru")
    let enValue = (int)x.Element("en")
    orderby ruValue
    select enValue
    ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is too late, but if you are wanting to parse the text and if it is an integer then sort by value otherwise sort by text, then this might help.

You need to define a function like this to enable parsing in LINQ expressions:

```
Func<string, int?> tryParseInteger = text =>
{
    int? result = null;
    int parsed;
    if (int.TryParse(text, out parsed))
    {
        result = parsed;
    }
    return result;
};
```

Then you can do queries like this:

```
var xs = new [] { "Hello", "3ff", "4.5", "5", };
var rs =
    (from x in xs
     select tryParseInteger(x)).ToArray();
// rs == new int?[] { null, null, null, 5, };
```

In your case you possibly want something like this:

```
var elements = new []
{
    "<desc><ru>AAA</ru></desc>",
    "<desc><ru>1</ru></desc>",
    "<desc><ru>42</ru></desc>",
    "<desc><ru>-7</ru></desc>",
    "<desc><ru>BBB</ru></desc>",
    "<desc><ru>22</ru></desc>",
};

var query =
    from e in elements
    let xe = XElement.Parse(e)
    let v = xe.Element("ru").Value
    orderby v
    orderby tryParseInteger(v)
    select v;
```

Which would give you:

```
{ "AAA", "BBB", "-7", "1", "22", "42" }
```

If you want to treat non-integers (ie parsed as null) to be zero then change the query by using this line:

```
    orderby tryParseInteger(v) ?? 0
```

Then you'll get this:

```
{ "-7", "AAA", "BBB", "1", "22", "42" }
```

I hope this helps.